# Windows compatibility error downloading exe files in PHP

Tags: php, header, download

I have set up a page using php and mysql that requires user to log in to download various paid for programs. They can click on a link as here and the program downloads and runs correctly.

```
$c3 = mysql_result($result,$i,"exe");
echo "<a href='$c3'>... etc
```

However, RT-click properties lets them see the path to that file, so I changed  the above to:

```
$c3="downloads3.php?link=".mysql_result($result,$i,"exe");
```

Where downloads3.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['link'];
$size = filesize($file);
$type = filetype($file);
$path = "../downloads/";
header('Content-Type: $type'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$path.$file");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 
readfile($file_url);?> 
?>
```

It finds the correct file and I get a security warning but on clicking run anyway it immediately gives a windows error message that the file is not compatible with this version of windows. Must be something in the above header but can't figure out what. Tried various permutations.

Any brill ideas, either of getting the above to work or other ways of hiding the source path? Thanks.

Comment: Two questions, where is $type defined, and is this happening on all version of Windows, or only specific version?  I'm assuming you've made sure the program truly is compatible when used directly?

Comment: What happens if you compare a downloaded file with its original? Save a hex dump of each and use diff to give you a comparison. It looks more like the EXE file has been corrupted. If the EXE files are large the script might be killed before the download completes too, again using diff on hex dumps will highlight what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's far more likely that the EXE is getting corrupted due to unexpected output. Your `downloads3.php` file has some extra output that will appear in the download:

```
readfile($file_url);?> //PHP stops parsing here 
?> //output "\n?>"
```

The PE header itself tells Windows what versions it can run on, so if any errors get generated before the file gets sent, they'll appear in the place Windows is expecting the header.

To mitigate this you can remove the extra newline and `?>` at the end of the file and turn error reporting off with `error_reporting(0)` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. $type = filetype($file) above, returns "file"

Answer (score 1):

The Best solution for here to get download file with any name what do you have want

```
function force_download($filename = '', $data = '')
{
    if ($filename == '' OR $data == '')
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Try to determine if the filename includes a file extension.
    // We need it in order to set the MIME type
    if (FALSE === strpos($filename, '.'))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Grab the file extension
    $x = explode('.', $filename);
    $extension = end($x);

    // Load the mime types
    if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') AND is_file(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes'.EXT))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes'.EXT);
    }
    elseif (is_file(APPPATH.'config/mimes'.EXT))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/mimes'.EXT);
    }

    // Set a default mime if we can't find it
    if ( ! isset($mimes[$extension]))
    {
        $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
    }
    else
    {
        $mime = (is_array($mimes[$extension])) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
    }

    // Generate the server headers
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE") !== FALSE)
    {
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
    }

    exit($data);
}

$data = 'Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';

force_download($name, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all the answers. $type = filetype($file) above, returns "file". Tried with "exe" but no different. The program runs on all versions of Windows and works fine with a direct download, just not with this code. Whatever it is downloading is not my file or not the complete one anyway. If I do "save as" the download is complete almost instantly and the file is only 1kb. It is 35Mb on the host. Also removed erroneous ?> and turned of error rep[orting but no different. Haven't tried Samad's code yet but I will.

Answer (score 0):

DOH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Too much cutting and pasting, that code has a really stupid error readfile($file_url) should be readfile($file), no wonder my 36Mb file was only 1KB after download, it was empty!

Thanks for all the comments, apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Erm. But it isn't much use anyway at hiding program path, which is stated in the "Do you want run or save" message. Ho hum.